# Passing variables through three pages

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I would like to pass variables through out three pages. 
The method I am currently using is:

1. Fist Page has a form e.g. `input type=”text” name=”username”`
2. Second page receives input from form on first page with the `$_POST` function
   e.g. `$username=$_POST[“username”]`
3. In order to keep the information from the first page stored, I created a session on the second page, and stored the input in it, e.g. as follows:
   `$_SESSION[“username”]=$username`
4. I then navigate to the third page and start my session. If I echo the stored input from my session, the server returns “undefined variable `username` ”. I’m guessing this is so, because the variable $username is by definition `$_POST[“username”]`, and in this case, there is no input for that post (being on the third page).

Of course I have tried converting the variable `$username` in a string and/or text with the `print()`/`print_r()` function. Doesn't change anything.

Does anyone have any solutions or workarounds to this issue?

I have come up with an unelegent way to solve the one problem: just recreate a copy of the form on the first page in the second page with the `value=$_POST[“username”]`…….but I need this to be a session, as these three pages are not linear (in other words, not steps 1,2,3, but steps 1,2,1,3 etc).

If it helps: this is a registration form (without passwords) with three pages. In the end, one must be able to navigate back to the pages to check ones inputs (so the data needs to be stored somewhere in order to call it up in the input fields).

Code page one (Inputs are in tables, left column specifies the what the Input is, right column the entry field):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="table_column_1"><p>Title </p></td>
    <td>
        <p><select name="title" class="dropdown" style="width:145px">
        <option>Bitte waehlen</option>
        <option value="Frau">Mr</option>
        <option value="Herr">Mrs</option>
        </select></p>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td class="table_column_1"><p>First name: </p></td>
    <td><p><input type="text" name="firstname"</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Surname: </p></td>
    <td><p><input type="text" name="surname" /></p></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td><p>Email: </p></td>
    <td><p><input type="email" name="email" /></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Company: </p></td>
    <td><p><input type="text" name="company" /></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="table_column_1"><p>Department: </p></td>
    <td><p><input type="text" name="department" /></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Code page two:

```
<?php

//Change variable to text/string
$title=print_r($_POST["title"]);
$firstname=print_r($_POST["firstname"]);
$surname=print_r($_POST["surname"]);
$email=print_r($_POST["email"]);
$company=print_r($_POST["company"]);
$department=print_r($_POST["department"]);

if ($title != "Bitte waehlen" && $firstname != "" && $surname != "" && $email != "" && $company != ""  &&$department != ""){
    session_start(1);
    echo "Session: RUNNING";

    //list for registration values
    $_SESSION["registration"]="YES";
    $_SESSION["title"]=$title;
    $_SESSION["firstname"]=$firstname;
    $_SESSION["surname"]=$surname;
    $_SESSION["email"]=$email;
    $_SESSION["company"]=$company;
    $_SESSION["department"]=$department;
    //Test session department and variable firstname validity
    echo $_SESSION["department"];
    echo $firstname;
    }
else{
    session_start(1);
    $_SESSION["registration"]="NO";
    echo "Session: NO";
    header("location: registration.php");
    };

?>
```

Code page three:

```
<?php

    session_start(1);
    echo "Session: RUNNING";

    //Check if session department data is returnable => no
    echo $_SESSION["department"];
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code please?

Comment: have you started session in step 3?

Comment: Did you write this up in word? You're using `“` and `”` a lot and this can effect your code.

Comment: yeah sure, how do i post code without "<>" being automatically removed by this Website.

Comment: session is started on page two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to show your code, but basically, this should work:

```
session_start();//before ANY output is sent to the client!
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    //redirect, or present user with error message
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

This sets `$_SESSION['username']` to the value of `$_POST['username']` if that post value was sent, and assigns the value of `$_SESSION['username']` to `$username` in all cases. if neither `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` have a username set, then there is an unexpected problem, and you should redirect, or show the user an error message...

---

After your code was posted, a couple of issues became obvious:

- `session_start` expects *no* arguments, you're passing `1`.
- `session_start` can only be called when the headers haven't been sent (ie: no output), you're calling `print_r`, which creates output.
- Don't use the closing `?>` tag, if your script only contains PHP (see php.net if you want to know why)
- Make sure there is no whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag
- Functions return values for a reason: `session_start` returns `false` if the session couldn't be created: **check return values**

This means that your page2.php script should look like this, more or less:

```
<?php
if (!session_start())
    exit('Output has already been sent!');//check for whitespace, use output buffering...
if (isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] !== 'Bitte waehlen')
{
    $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
    $_SESSION["registration"]="YES";
    //avoid notices, always use isset:
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : null;
}
else
{
    //form wasn't submitted, or the title was "Bitte waehlen":
    // show error message, or redirect
}
```

Comment: I did so, but the third page is problematic for some reason, as it doesn't return e.g. $_SESSION['username']

Comment: @user3651945: Check the [signature of `session_start`](http://www.php.net/function.session-start): `bool session_start ( void );` <== you're passing an argument (`session_start(1)`) while PHP expects `void`. Also note that you can't start a session _after_ output has already been sent: `print_r` sends output. Don't use that function anyway: post data is always going to be a string. Also make sure there is _no_ whitespace before the `<?php` tag

Comment: Wow this did the trick! thanks so much!! could you explain what exactly line 7 does? It works, but I'm not fimiliar with the code.

Comment: @user3651945: `$var = <expression> ? <value1> : <value2>` is using the ternary operator. It's short for `if (<expression>) { $var = <value1>; } else { $var = <value2>;}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you are using register globals.

Now that is your first error. Don't use it. Just don't.

Then, you are storing the username in a session, so now you can access it using

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

Also, when storing data in a session you also need to call session_start(); before assigning any data to your session.